# I am trying to display info from a database in a grid format with PHP and HTML but it is just going vertically

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-5

Code should create a grid of the database info, but no matter what it just keeps putting it all vertically and not in the rows/cols like it should.
Maybe I am brain dead from looking at code all day but I cannot see where I have gone wrong. Anyone wanna look at it for me?
I have noticed that it wraps each `<div class="col">` with a DIV with the `row` class. I moved around where
I have it writing `<div class="row">` and that just messes it up more

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }
                
                // Set Vars
                $max_columns = 4;
                $record_id   = 0;
                $sql         = "SELECT * from `" . $_SESSION['userName'] . "_T-table`";
                $result      = $conn->query($sql);
                
                $row1 = $result->num_rows;    // Find total rows returned by database
                if($row1 > 0) {
                    $cols = 2;    // Define number of columns
                    $counter = 1;     // Counter used to identify if we need to start or end a row
                    $nbsp = $cols - ($row1 % $cols);    // Calculate the number of blank columns
                    
                    
                    while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        if(($counter % $cols) == 1) {    // Check if it's new row
                            echo '<div class="row" id="Row 1">';    
                        } ?>
                        <div class="col" id="Rep1">
                            <div class="card text-bg-dark mb-3" id="<?PHP echo $column ?>" style="max-width: 30%; max-height:30%;">
                                <img src="/users/<?PHP echo $_SESSION["userName"] ?>/images/<?PHP echo $rows["img_loc"] ?>" class="card-img img-fluid">
                                    <div class="card-img-overlay">
                                        <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $rows["scientific_name"] ?>
                                            <span class="text-warning-emphasis"><?php echo $row["common_name"]?></span>
                                        </h5>
                                        Sex: <?PHP echo $rows["t_sex"] ?>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="card-text">Name: <?PHP echo $rows["t_name"] ?>
                                        <br>
                                        Age: <?PHP echo $rows["t_age"] ?>
                                        <br>
                                        Hatched on: <?PHP echo $rows["hatch_date"] ?>
                                        <br>
                                        Arrived: <?PHP echo $rows["arrival_date"] ?>
                                        <br>
                                        Last fed on: <?PHP  echo $rows["last_feed_date"] ?>
                                        <br>
                                        Food type: <?PHP echo $rows["feed_types"] ?>
                                        <br>
                                        Last molt: <?PHP echo $rows["last_molt_date"] ?>
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="card-text"><?PHP echo $rows["t_notes"] ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <?PHP
                        }
                        $counter++;    // Increase the counter
                    }
                    $result->free();
                    if($nbsp > 0) { // Add unused column in last row
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $nbsp; $i++)  { 
                            echo '<div class="col></div>';      
                        }
                        echo '</div>';
```

Out Put HTML

```
<div class="row" id="Row 1">                        <div class="col" id="Rep1">
                            <div class="card text-bg-dark mb-3" id="" style="max-width: 30%; max-height:30%;">
                                <img src="/users/xxxxx/images/mj.png" class="card-img img-fluid">
                                    <div class="card-img-overlay">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">assf                                         <span class="text-warning-emphasis"></span>
                                        </h5>
                                        Sex: asdfa                                      <br>
                                        <p class="card-text">Name: 1                                        <br>
                                        Age: asdf                                       <br>
                                        Hatched on: asdf                                        <br>
                                        Arrived: asdf                                       <br>
                                        Last fed on: asdf                                       <br>
                                        Food type: asdf                                     <br>
                                        Last molt: asdf                                     </p>
                                        <p class="card-text">                                   </p></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

There should be 2 `<div class="col">` per row not one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap Table to format your output.

[Bootstrap Table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/)

Comment: I am quite familiar with bootstrap, and am using ver 5.3.0 The issue is more with my PHP code.